# Datamodeling, constraints and issue with my model

Tags: mysql, constraints, data-modeling

I am designing **an application that will allow for childminders/nannies to find babies to look after and parents to find childminders/nannies that will look after their children**.

I would like to have a single `ACCOUNT` database table both for parents and childminders.

However, there are some slight differences between parent accounts and childminder accounts i.e.

- childminders can have a curriculum/resume attached to their account (materialized by a `RESUME` database table)
- childminder accounts are further refined by a childminder statuses (Nanny, Baby-sitter, etc.) (materialized by a `CHILDMINDER_STATUS` database table). A childminder can have one or more "childminder statuses".

I am not sure what the relationships between the `ACCOUNT`, `RESUME` and `CHILDMINDER_STATUS` should be...

P.S. I use MySQL server.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that an `ACCOUNT` belonging to a childminder has zero or more `ADVERTISEMENT` that belong only to a childminder. Same thing with `ACCOUNTs` belonging to a parent together with their `ADVERTISEMENTs`.

Comment: Did that answer your question, or do you have concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works - does it answer your question? Other tables would follow in the same way.

```
create table account (
  id int unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  fname varchar(100),
  lname varchar(100),
  type enum('parent','childminder')
  -- etc - add other fields needed for both parents and childminders
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table resume (
  id int unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  account_id int unsigned,
  file_spec varchar(100),
  -- other fields as necessary
  CONSTRAINT `resume_account_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table childminder_status (
  id int unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  account_id int unsigned,
  status_description varchar(100),
  -- other fields as necessary
  CONSTRAINT `childminder_status_account_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```